# How to extract files in S3 on the fly with boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to find a way to extract .gz files in S3 on the fly, that is no need to download it to locally, extract and then push it back to S3.

With boto3 + lambda, how can i achieve my goal?

I didn't see any extract part in boto3 document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract .gz files in S3 automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51257796/extract-gz-files-in-s3-automatically)

Comment: You can set an event based trigger that detects .zip or .gz that runs a lambda function. With that lambda function, you can read files into a buffer, unzip or modify them and reupload them back to S3. Here's a detailed explanation with the code: https://betterprogramming.pub/unzip-and-gzip-incoming-s3-files-with-aws-lambda-f7bccf0099c9

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Amazon S3 is a storage service. There is no in-built capability to manipulate the content of files.

However, you could use an AWS Lambda function to retrieve an object from S3, decompress it, then upload content back up again. However, please note that there is default limit of 500MB in temporary disk space for Lambda, so avoid decompressing too much data at the same time.

You could configure the S3 bucket to trigger the Lambda function when a new file is created in the bucket. The Lambda function would then:

- Use boto3 to download the new file
- Use the `gzip` Python library to extract files
- Use boto3 to upload the resulting file(s)

Sample code:

```py
import gzip
import io

import boto3

bucket = '<bucket_name>'
key = '<key_name>'

s3 = boto3.client('s3', use_ssl=False)
compressed_file = io.BytesIO(
    s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)['Body'].read())
uncompressed_file = gzip.GzipFile(None, 'rb', fileobj=compressed_file)
s3.upload_fileobj(Fileobj=uncompressed_file, Bucket=bucket, Key=key[:-3])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know the temporary space for Lambda is 500 MB. That space is too small in my case. I think i'll go with traditional method.

Comment: This would certainly work if you knew the uncompressed payload was less than 500MB.

Comment: I got an error (ValueError: Seek from end not supported) while using this method.

Comment: @ie979 Please create a new question if you wish to obtain assistance.

Comment: I added my key  Key="raw/20190630.csv.zip" but what means the Key=uncompressed_key?? I wrote a string but I obtained the next error 
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'PK')

Comment: @Maggyero I have rolled-back your changes. Feel free to add your own answer with alternative code. Also, please note that the service name is "Amazon S3", not "AWS S3".

Comment: I understand, I like your neat formatting without temporary variables. The only issue is the mismatch between `zipfile` in the text and `gzip` in the code, and the missing import statements (`import gzip` and `import io`). Thanks for the remark on the Amazon service name (now I am surprised that it is not also ‘Amazon Lambda’).

Comment: @Maggyero Thanks for the explanation, I'll update for those fixes. Also FYI: [naming conventions - Why some services are called "AWS XXX" and the others "Amazon XXX" - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125790/why-some-services-are-called-aws-xxx-and-the-others-amazon-xxx)

Comment: Thanks for the link and update. I am wondering if we really need to `read()` the S3 file object then wraps the data into a `io.BytesIO` to get a file object back before passing it to the `upload_fileobj` method. Can’t we just pass the S3 file object directly?

Comment: @Maggyero We could only pass the object directly if we use the [smart-open · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/) library, since most libraries expect a file on the local disk.

Comment: Sorry I meant we need not read and wrap into an `io.BytesIO` the S3 file object, we can pass it directly to the `gzip.GzipFile` constructor like this: `gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)['Body'])`. Because according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile): ‘The new class instance is based on *fileobj*, which can be a regular file, an `io.BytesIO` object, or any other object which simulates a file.’ We also need not provide *filename* (it defaults to that of *fileobj* or `''`) nor *mode* (it defaults to `'rb'`) arguments.

Comment: Do you confirm that?

Answer (score 25):

You can use BytesIO to stream the file from S3, run it through gzip, then pipe it back up to S3 using `upload_fileobj` to write the BytesIO.

```py
# python imports
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
import gzip

# setup constants
bucket = '<bucket_name>'
gzipped_key = '<key_name.gz>'
uncompressed_key = '<key_name>'

# initialize s3 client, this is dependent upon your aws config being done 
s3 = boto3.client('s3', use_ssl=False)  # optional
s3.upload_fileobj(                      # upload a new obj to s3
    Fileobj=gzip.GzipFile(              # read in the output of gzip -d
        None,                           # just return output as BytesIO
        'rb',                           # read binary
        fileobj=BytesIO(s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=gzipped_key)['Body'].read())),
    Bucket=bucket,                      # target bucket, writing to
    Key=uncompressed_key)               # target key, writing to
```

Ensure that your key is reading in correctly:

```py
# read the body of the s3 key object into a string to ensure download
s = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=gzip_key)['Body'].read()
print(len(s))  # check to ensure some data was returned
```

Comment: Hi Todd, i got this error when executing this code
ValueError: Seek from end not supported

Comment: Seems that you probably did not download any data. Test out the script by running the read into a python string and then check the first few bytes of the string to ensure it is what you expected

Comment: Is this possible to do without knowing my keys? The only thing I know is my aws region. I am not an administrative user and helpdesk is extremely reluctant to provide me with 
the keys.

Comment: [ERROR] TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fileobj'

Comment: Harry, sounds like you have a syntax error. Probably misplaced parentheses. Can you share the command syntax?

Comment: @ToddJones can you please tell how to repurpose this code for `7z` zipfiles

Comment: @ToddJones Can you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696939/python-convert-large-zip-file-to-gz-file

Answer (score 21):

The above answers are for `gzip` files, for `zip` files, you may try

```py
import boto3
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO
bucket = 'bucket1'

s3 = boto3.client('s3', use_ssl=False)
Key_unzip = 'result_files/'

prefix      = "folder_name/"
zipped_keys =  s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter = "/")
file_list = []
for key in zipped_keys['Contents']:
    file_list.append(key['Key'])
#This will give you list of files in the folder you mentioned as prefix
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
#Now create zip object one by one, this below is for 1st file in file_list
zip_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=bucket, key=file_list[0])
print (zip_obj)
buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())

z = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
for filename in z.namelist():
    file_info = z.getinfo(filename)
    s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
        z.open(filename),
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key='result_files/' + f'{filename}')
```

This will work for your `zip` file and your result unzipped data will be in `result_files` folder. Make sure to increase memory and time on `AWS Lambda` to maximum since some files are pretty large and needs time to write.

Comment: when calling z.open im getting `AttributeError: '_SharedFile' object has no attribute 'writing'` error.

Comment: I am getting an Python int too large to convert to C long for the "buffer=BytestIO(zip..." call for a 2GB zip file.  Is there a limit to the size of the buffer?

Comment: @DougBower I processed 7GB+ so I am not sure if there is any limit considering its continuous way of parsing.

Comment: @Harry_pb Any other ideas on what would cause the overflow?  One additional detail this is running in an AWS Lambda with 4GB.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a large zip file with BytesIO caused memory error.

I was opening 6GB+ zip files full of files that were to be placed in another folder.  With the *buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())*, I was getting out of memory errors as it would buffer the body into memory. I had limited the memory on the lambda as I could possibly receive larger files and wanted to make sure it was streaming and lambda max memory of 10120 would not be an issue. I used the python [smart_open](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open) as a layer to stream the zip file in to process it.

**The lambda uses less than 150mb and @500sec** to process the 6GB+ zip files. So the lambda max 900sec becomes your limiting factor and would require an async process of each extracted file to overcome.

```
layers_dir = '/opt'
sys.path.insert(0, layers_dir)
from smart_open import open
class Unzip():
    ...
    def process_zip(self):
       with zipfile.ZipFile(open(f's3://{self.bucket}/{self.key}', 'rb', transport_params={'client':self.s3.client})) as zip_ref:
          for file_info in zip_ref.infolist():
              if not file_info.is_dir():
                 file_name = file_info.filename
                 key = os.path.join(self.outputPath, file_name) 
                 print(f'Extracting {key}')
                 with zip_ref.open(file_name, 'r') as data:
                     self.s3.client.upload_fileobj(
                                Fileobj=data,
                                Bucket=self.bucket,
                                Key=key
                            )
```

Another option to try would be the [s3Wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66594170/1516104)