# extracting zip files to a s3 bucket in django project

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip

I am new to Django and aws. I want to extract the zip file uploaded by the user in Django, files are stored perfectly in the s3 bucket when the user uploads it, but the problem is I am not able to extract the files to the s3 folder

```
new_folder_name = random.randint(0, 68764446643313679)
folder_unzip = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'Unzipped')
print(folder_unzip)
file_path = os.path.join(folder_unzip, str(new_folder_name))
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(self.ebook)
zip_file.extractall(file_path)
```

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: I think you have to use file_upload using the **s3** module, which states how to upload file one by one, you will find tons of module.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276201/how-to-extract-files-in-s3-on-the-fly-with-boto3